# How to convert pagination numbers to arabic numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui, antd

I use ant design or material ui pagination . I try to change latin numbers to arabic numbers but I can't do it . I tried ant design localization but it doesn't affect pagination numbers .

```
import { Pagination } from 'antd';

<Pagination defaultCurrent={1} total={50} />
```

How can I turn it's numbers to arabic numbers ?

Comment: The [documentation seems to be showing arabic numbers](https://ant.design/components/pagination/), so I'm guessing that latin numbers are coming from your project?

Comment: Also, it is unclear if you're referring to [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) and [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), or to any other numerals.

Comment: @EmileBergeron How can I turn latin numbers to ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۱۰ in the pagination component of ant design ?

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. Also, note that 0123456789 are also known as Arabic numbers, and I believe that Latin numbers are usually understood as the Roman numerals I, II, III, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vthmt5?file=src/App.js)

```
const arabicNumbers = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
function convertNumberToLetter(num) {
  let result = ""
  const str = num.toString();
  for(let c of str){
    result += arabicNumbers.charAt(c)
  }
  return result
}

function itemRender(current, type, originalElement) {
  if (type === 'page') {
    return <a>{convertNumberToLetter(current)}</a>;
  }
  return originalElement;
}
```

in JSX:

```
<Pagination defaultCurrent={1} total={50} itemRender={itemRender}  />
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir !